# Java code, could use some assistance

Tags: java

Anyone know the answer to this question? studying for an exam atm and it looks like this is coming up.

```
 b) Amend the Person class so the code snippet below will work properly
 ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

 //Assume Person objects have been added to the list

 if (people.contains(new Person("Adam Ant", 48)))
 {
 //Do something
 }
 else
 {
 //Do something else
 }
```

Comment: First you need to provide everything you have, including the Person class, then we can start helping you, but the general idea is that you need to implement/override the compareTo() method

Comment: Have you consider how `people` knows if it contains a particular object?  How that comparison might work?

Comment: read the doc. here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

*Amend the Person class so the code snippet below will work properly*

Override `Object.equals(Object)` in `Person`. Something like,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Person) {
        Person p = (Person) obj;
        return this.name.equals(p.name) && this.age == p.age;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's also a good practice to override `hashCode` (or your `Person` won't work correctly with some `Collection`s). Something like,

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode() + age;
}
```

Comment: Should always override hashCode when you do it for equals; see Joshua Bloch "Effective Java".

Comment: @duffymo Good advice. Edited.